# jquery function inside a long process

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery script:

```
$("#theid").fadeTo(1000,0.01).getxmo().fadeTo(1000,1);

function getxmo(){
    $('#output').append('okay!');
}
```

It is not running the function part...

What's the correct syntax to run a function in this way please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than chaining the call to your `getxmo()` function, put it in the callback function of the first `fadeTo()` call:

```
$("#theid").fadeTo(1000, 0.01, getxmo).fadeTo(1000,1);

function getxmo() {
    $('#output').append('okay!');
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pj7Kw/)

Answer (score 1):

This can't work. You have to create a jQuery plugin

```
$.fn.getxmo = function() {
      $('#output').append('okay!');
}
```

Read more about jQuery plugins [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)